# Return count of multiple words existing in pandas column

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like below with column name 'texts'

```
texts
throne one
bar one
foo two
bar three
foo two
bar two
foo one
foo three
one three
```

I want to count presence of three words 'one' and 'two' and 'three' for each row and return count of matches for these words, if it is a complete word. Output will look like below.

```
    texts   counts
    throne one  1
    bar one     1
    foo two     1
    bar three   1
    foo two     1
    bar two     1
    foo one     1
    foo three   1
    one three   2
```

you can see than for the first row, count is 1 as 'throne' was not considered as one of the value being searched 'one' is not a complete word and instead it is 'throne'.

Any help on this?

Comment: @MattR `one three` has count 2 as i am originally searching for count of `one`, `two` and `three`. in the last row, both the values are present. So it is rightly giving count of 2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `pd.Series.str.count` with a regex by joining `words` with `'|'`

```
words = 'one two three'.split()

df.assign(counts=df.texts.str.count('|'.join(words)))

        texts  counts
0  throne one       2
1     bar one       1
2     foo two       1
3   bar three       1
4     foo two       1
5     bar two       1
6     foo one       1
7   foo three       1
8   one three       2
```

---

In order to nail down `'throne'`, as in don't count it, we can add some word boundaries to the regex

```
words = 'one two three'.split()

df.assign(counts=df.texts.str.count('|'.join(map(r'\b{}\b'.format, words))))

        texts  counts
0  throne one       1
1     bar one       1
2     foo two       1
3   bar three       1
4     foo two       1
5     bar two       1
6     foo one       1
7   foo three       1
8   one three       2
```

---

And for flair, using the raw form of f-strings in Python 3.6

```
words = 'one two three'.split()

df.assign(counts=df.texts.str.count('|'.join(fr'\b{w}\b' for w in words)))

        texts  counts
0  throne one       1
1     bar one       1
2     foo two       1
3   bar three       1
4     foo two       1
5     bar two       1
6     foo one       1
7   foo three       1
8   one three       2
```

Comment: first row shouldn't give count of 2 as i am only looking for complete words. `throne` is a different word and cannot be considered for `one`

Comment: Thank you very much. It did exactly what i requested for. I will accept this as answer.